# Windows 10 installation driver not found after using dd

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, dd

I wrote Windows 10 iso file to a usb using `dd`. This is the command I used:

```
sudo dd if=windows.iso of=/dev/sdb1 bs=1MB conv=fdatasync status=progress
```

The computer that I want to reinstall Windows 10 on currently has Ubuntu 18.04. I formatted my USB file type to be FAT before I wrote to it. When I went into the boot menu, the installation starts up, but it notified me of a missing driver.

[image: Windows setup - Select the driver to be installed.]

I tried browsing through the system to find the driver but it was no use. Then I thought this was a file type issue, so I formatted the USB file type to NTFS and rewrite the Windows iso to it again. The same issue occurred. I opened up Startup Disk Creator, but it doesn't even detect the Windows iso.

Is this a common issue with trying to create a Windows boot USB with `dd`? Will I need to use a third-party program for it?

Comment: Try using /dev/sdb as the output. If the Windows ISO is a hybrid, and works from USB, that should work.

Comment: Thank you. Scrolled down the post and found WoeUSB which is a more recent fork of WinUSB. In the process of installing Windows right now.